# Show that $x^x$ grows faster than $b^x$ as $x \to \infty$ for $b > 1$

Tags: limits

I have been searching for this for a while, but I can't understand it from my textbook. I am supposed to:

"Show that $x^x$ grows faster than $b^x$ as $x \to \infty$ for $b > 1$"

I can't figure out why the value of $b$ really matters when they have the same limit and exponent.

Comment: @Itay4 Then again, $x^x$ also grows faster than $(\frac12)^x$ ...

Comment: Additionally, the function $(\frac{x}{b})^x$ is strictly increasing for $x/b > 1$.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen $b>1$

Comment: How about showing that $\ln x^x$ grows faster than $\ln b^x$?

Comment: Note that for all $x>b>1$, $x^x>b^x>1$. We are able to assume $x>b$, because $b$ is fixed and $x\rightarrow\infty$.

Comment: The value of $b$ matters simply because if $0<b<1$, $b^x$ *decreases* to $0$!

Comment: @Bernard answers this question. Also, the title is badly chosen. What does this have to do with l'Hospital's rule?

Comment: @Bernard: so the behavior is the same for $b\ge0$ as for $b>1$ and the latter inequality is optional.

Comment: @mickep you are right, we have just been going over it in class and I mindlessly just titled it that.

Comment: @Jeff for future reference, it is possible to [edit] questions (or link below the post.) I changed the title.

Answer (score 9):

The intuition behind this is that while both $x^x$ and $b^x$ for $b>1$ have the same limit, the first expression in increasing in both the  base and the exponent, whereas the second is only increasing in the exponent.  So, for any fixed $b$, $x^x$ will eventually attain a base greater than $b$ and so will grow faster in the long run.

The math behind it is to look at 
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{x^{x}}{b^{x}}
$$
and show that goes to infinity for any $b>1$, though I'll let you fill in the details.

Answer (score 2):

If $x>b$ then $\frac{x}{b}>c>1$ and when $x\to \infty$ we have

$$\left(\frac{x}{b}\right)^x>c^x\to \infty$$

Answer (score 2):

For $\dfrac xb>1$, $\left(\dfrac xb\right)^x$ goes to infinity.

Answer (score 1):

$b^x=o(x^x)$ when $x \longrightarrow \infty$

$\lim_{x \longrightarrow \infty} \frac{b^x}{x^x}=\lim_{x \longrightarrow \infty}e^{-x(\ln{x}-\ln{b})}=0$